# Ruby check if something is mounted(--bind) in this directory

Tags: ruby, binding, mount

```
mount
    /project on /mount_1 type none (rw,bind)
    /project on /mount_2 type none (rw,bind)
    /project on /mount_3 type none (rw,bind)
```

How to check with ruby(not shell!!) whether some dir is mounted on /mount_X?

Is there something easier than opening /proc/mounts and looking for /mount_X there?

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it is:

```
system("mount|grep /mount_X")
```

Answer (score 1):

As long as you are under linux, you find many answers directly by reading from the filesystem:

```ruby
File.open('/proc/mounts').each do |line|
  device, mount_point, file_system_type, mount_options, dump, fsck_order  = line.split(" ")
end
```

which leads to the following solution for your problem:

```ruby
if File.readlines('/proc/mounts').any?{ |line| line.split(" ")[1] == "/mount_X"}
    puts "Yes, it is mounted!!!"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just parse the output of the `mount` command:

```
`mount`.split("\n").grep(/bind/).map { |x| x.split(" ")[2]  }
```

Answer (score 0):

a little twist to @tvw's answer did it for me. Read /proc/mounts line by line and do a partial string match on the 
 mountpoint full path `mountpoint/folder_name` .

```
 raise "Failed:  not mounted" 
 unless File.readlines('/proc/mounts').any?{ |line| line.split(" ")[1] =~ /folder_name$/ }
```